# Security issues with three browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) and websockets using autobahn

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, websocket, microsoft-edge

I am using an autobahn server from this example: https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo_tls

and following the mentioned in the example instructions, I generated the server keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
openssl x509 -in server.crt -out server.pem
```

I also have an autobahn-js client:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="autobahn.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var connection = new autobahn.Connection({url: 'wss://domain.com'});

connection.onopen = function (session) {

   // 1) subscribe to a topic
   function onevent(args) {
      console.log("Event:", args[0]);
   }
   session.subscribe('com.myapp.hello', onevent);

   // 2) publish an event
   session.publish('com.myapp.hello', ['Hello, world!']);

   // 3) register a procedure for remoting
   function add2(args) {
      return args[0] + args[1];
   }
   session.register('com.myapp.add2', add2);

   // 4) call a remote procedure
   session.call('com.myapp.add2', [2, 3]).then(
      function (res) {
         console.log("Result:", res);
      }
   );
};

connection.open();
</script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

However, running the above js-code in three popular browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox), revealed security issues in the connection which I am pasting here using each browser's console.

**Google Chrome**:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://domain/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
(anonymous) @   autobahn.min.js:196
```

**Microsoft Edge**:

```
SCRIPT12045: WebSocket Error: Network Error 12045, The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect
```

**Mozilla Firefox**:

On Firefox's case it's the server that complains about the client's ca with the following message:

```
2017-11-15T09:04:38+0000 Connection to/from tcp4:<ip here> lost (<class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>): [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca')])
2017-11-15T09:04:38+0000 _connectionLost: [Failure instance: Traceback: <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca')]
```

Are the keys generated with the "openssl" tool not good enough for browsers? How can I solve this problem? Why is Firefox not complaining about the server's security?

Comment: The problem is that the browsers don't accept the self-signed certificate. Which is good, otherwise anyone could pose as any domain with a self-signed cert. You need to convince your browsers to accept the certificate, which has been widely discussed elsewhere.

Comment: If you mean configuring the browser to accept my certificate, it is not an option since the client is gonna be used by many non-technical users. It must be a configuration in the server/client/certificates

Comment: A self-signed certificate is obviously only good for local development/testing. To deploy this to a wide range of users, you'll have to get a real certificate.

Comment: And you are confident this is the only problem that we have with Chrome & Edge? Can the SSL configuration (i.e. version) be also a problem in our case?

Comment: The errors are all about the CA (certificate authority), which is clearly this issue.